# Redis make test Errors?

Tags: redis

When I run redis make test i get these errors.

```
Makefile:242: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-stable/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

These are the errors

```
Slave should be able to synchronize with the master in tests/integration/replication-psync.tcl
```

I am using ubuntu 16 + apache

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error when running `make test` on DO droplet with 512mb RAM.
Googled some solutions but nothing helps until I've resized droplet to 1gb RAM.

The error disappears and I've passed the test.

Maybe you're running into the same issue with lack of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, so, as per suggestion from Audrey, I found that all my RAM was being used up by other apps, so I freed up some RAM (~ 2GB) and got it working